# An if statement is not working whit text colors

Tags: javascript, html, sass

Ok basically what I am trying to do is toggleing the color of a  p element taht changes but is like if the condition is always false:

```
Html:

<p id="brand-element-Samsung" onclick="itemSelectedSamsung()" style="color: #ff0000">Samsung</p>


Sass:

p
              width: 50%
              margin: 25px 23px 20px 23px
              padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px
              cursor: pointer
              &:hover
                color: #a3abb1
                transition: color .2s ease


Js:

function itemSelectedSamsung() {
  var inactiveColor = "#ff0000"
  var activeColor = "#2c3e50"
  var hoveredColor = "#a3abb1"
  var text = document.getElementById('brand-element-Samsung')
  text.style.transition = "all .2s ease"
  text.style.color === activeColor ? text.style.color = inactiveColor : text.style.color = activeColor
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but `activeColor ? text.style.color = inactiveColor : text.style.color = activeColor` looks wrong. `activeColor` is a string, but you're treating it like a boolean. Were you trying to determine the truthiness of `activeColor`?

Comment: Also I'm 90% certain `text.style.color ===` should be `text.style.color =`. Did you mean to assign `text.style.color` to a new value? Because you need to use the assignment operator (`=`) to do that.

Comment: yes, this is wht I am trying to do

Comment: I was tryoing to toggle between the colors

Comment: OK, well `activateColor` is always going to be truthy, since you're setting it to a non-empty string constant. That else condition is never going to be evaluated.

Comment: How can I manage to get it to be consoidered thruly only when the color is white

Comment: You have three colors. It's not clear to me looking at your code what conditions they should be set. Can you explain the conditions in plain English?

Comment: If the color of the text is equal to white, set it to #2c3e50 else set it to white

Comment: Then the statement should be `text.style.color = (text.style.color === inactiveColor) ? activeColor: inactiveColor`.

Comment: It works only 1 time, i am trying to toggle between the colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out your `text.style.color`. It will be in `rgba()` format and not as stated by CSS rule in HEX format. That's why it's not working.

So you should also use `rgba()` for `activeColor`.

*BUT* better approach is to check if element has certain class and put colors in CSS rules:

```
.brand-element-Samsung {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.brand-element-Samsung.active {
    color: #2c3e50;
}

$(document).on('click', '.brand-element-Samsung', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```